# How to go from php MySQL sql injection vulnerable query to a MySQLi not vulnerable query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

im learning MySQLi in order to make my site not vulnerable to SQL injections (wich is now) but i get confuse when i was trying to "translate" my old querys to MySQLi statements, so i hope you can help me with some examples so i can get it. Thanks a lot!.

**Updating my site counter**

```
$sql = "UPDATE post SET counter = counter+1 WHERE id=".$tget;
```

**Sorting my comments**

```
$info=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE idpost=" . $tget . " AND active=1 ORDER BY datetime DESC");
```

**Saving the comment**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `comments` (`id`, `idpost`, `comment`, `datetime`, `author`, `active`) VALUES (NULL, '" . addslashes($_POST['idcomment']) . "', '" . addslashes($_POST['comment']) . "', NOW(), '" . addslashes($_POST['name']) . "', '1');";
```

If you can explain me how to go from here to MySQLi i can finish with the others querys.

And by way, if you (**expert**) consider that there is other way to protect me from sql injections better than MySQLi, please tell me about it.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but there is another way, it's called PDO: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$conn = new mysqli(…);
$sql = "UPDATE post SET counter = counter+ 1 WHERE id= ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $tget);
$stmt->execute();
```

In the first argument to `bind_param`, use a string of `i`, `s`, `d` and `b` to set the parameter types:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (int_column, string_column, double_column, blob_column, another_int_column VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("isdbi", $int_val, $string_val, $double_val, $blob_val, $another_int_val);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$stmt->execute;` be `$stmt->execute();`?  And shouldn't you have `$stmt->close();` after each query?

Comment: @Rocket: sure, updated. There should be also `$stmt->fetch()` for the `SELECT` queries, but I omitted it for the sake of brevity, since the @op wanted to know how to bind.

Answer (score 0):

my experiencia tell with you use stored procedure with bind_param option. you need read this post for more detail.

[Use one bind_param() with variable number of input vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793471/use-one-bind-param-with-variable-number-of-input-vars)