# Dealing with a variable number of input fields

Tags: php, mysqli

I have some javascript code that generates additional input fields. So, I can know how many inputs the user will insert (or I can block the number of clones...)

so I have

```
$form['input'][0];
$form['input'][1];
$form['input'][2];
and so on.
```

#### First problem

Determine how many `$form['input'][]`

Is this correct?

```
for $i=0; $i<$form.length[input][]; $i++ {
 $form['input'][$i];
}
```

and the query

#### Second problem

```
// number of ? must change  
($sql = $db -> prepare("INSERT INTO user (something) VALUES (?, ?)"));

$user = 1;
// problem here. this must change dynamically to the number of inputs for each user.
$sql -> bind_param('iss', $user, $form['input'][0], $form['input'][1]);
$sql->execute();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show data structure.  How is the data being saved.

Comment: var formdata = $("#customForm").serializeArray(); and  data: formdata,

Comment: Does each element in the $form['input'] array represent a row to be inserted?

Comment: Wait wait, I think I thought the answer to my question (and what you said isn't it :p).  Is the user selecting fields that are on the user table in the database?  So is there a limit to the number of fields that can be added?

Comment: I found a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793471/use-one-bind-param-with-variable-number-of-input-vars

Comment: "INSERT INTO user (something) VALUES (?, ?) <-that will not work you only stipulate one field (something) not (something, something_else)

Comment: i am thinking to limit the number of cloned fields, and insert null if the input is none.

Comment: @wire: if the number of input fields is variable and they are all the same type of data (like test scores) you need two database tables and a many-to-one relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determine how many `$form['input']`: `count($form['input']);`.