# function to dynamic insert to Database using mysqli prepare

Tags: php, mysqli

i need help with my function thet i build , i trying to use MYSQLI prepare but i am not so good .

this is my function :

```
   function insertToDb($table,$rowsarray,$valuequestionmarks,$lenstrings,$valarray){

        $this->mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
        if ($insert_stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO $table ($rowsarray) 
         VALUES 
        ($valuequestionmarks)"
        ))
        {
        $insert_stmt->bind_param("$lenstrings",$valarray);
        // Execute the prepared query.
        if(!$insert_stmt->execute())
            {
             die("Execute failed: (" . $insert_stmt->errno . ") " . $insert_stmt->error);
            }
        }

   }
```

And this is how i call :

```
                   $img = "something.jpg";
                   $uip = ulUtils::GetRemoteIP(false);
                   $table='forgotpassqm';
                   $rowsarray = 'email,text,img,ip';
                   $valuequestionmarks ='?,?,?,?';
                   $lenstrings ='ssss';
                   $valarray ='$email,$text,$img,$uip';

                   $func->insertToDb($table,$rowsarray,$valuequestionmarks,$lenstrings,$valarray);
```

And i keep get this error :

```
  Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables
```

And the execute error :

```
Execute failed: (2031) No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement
```

i tryed allot of combination none work , i read other question none as my , and none worked or help either.

And i know this is about the ssss , but i using 4 and its seem to be alright so where i wrong here ?
Thanks allot.

EDIT :

```
$table output : forgotpassqm .
$rowsaray output: email,text,img,ip .
$valuequestionmarks output : ?,?,?,? .
$lenstrings output: ssss.
$valarray output: $email,$text,$img,$uip.
```

I think the problem is at $valarray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the looks of it you are attempting to send a comma-delimited list of variables as an array (not how an array works) and you are using single quotes so variables aren't being interpolated to their values.

`bind_param()` expects a list of arguments after the type definitions.  You aren't sending a list, you are sending the string `'$email,$text,$img,$uip'`.
Your call to that function should look like this:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $email, $text, $img, $uip);
```

Comment: What wrong with how i did ? did you look how i inserted the paramters via vars?

Comment: Yes, I did, however the statement you have of `$valarray ='$email,$text,$img,$uip';` is nothing more than a string since you are using single quotes.  I think I see what you are trying to do, but I would suggest you approach the implementation a bit different.

Comment: Ok i got it , i debuged and this is the problem , you have suggesion? maybe i use it as array() and then in the function i will use list ?

Comment: Have a look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793471/use-one-bind-param-with-variable-number-of-input-vars  I think that will talks about what you are looking to do there (dynamic amount of vars).