# Advanced Search PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have an advanced search with 4 fields, only one `name_first` is mandatory

There are many variations of search as the other fields are not mandatory so I need a select statement that only selects the fields that have been populated, but there are so many variations

I have tried the below script but it does not show the correct information (I think it is completely wrong?!)

```
$name_first=$_GET["name_first"];
$status=$_GET["status"];
$type=$_GET["type"];
$manstaff=$_GET["manstaff"];

$result401=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `hr_employees` WHERE 
    (name_first LIKE '$name_first%') 
            AND 
    (status LIKE '$status%') 
            AND 
    (manages_staff LIKE '$manstaff%');")or die('Error' . mysql_error());
```

Any ideas what the script above should be? Basically if the field isnt completed it doesnt need to search for it?

Comment: change this `$name_first%` to this `%$name_first%`

Comment: Thanks, however it still doesnt cover all the variations of search? If I  complete a field EG status to something that doesnt match the name_first it still brings up a result based on name_first if that makes sense?

Comment: why you use AND instead of OR ?? any reason ?? and why `name_first IS NULL` ??

Comment: As if all the fields are completed it would need to be AND?

Comment: So in worst case if there is only first variable is set then ??

Comment: just search that variable, if 2 search 2 if 3 search 3 etc..

Comment: why `name_first IS NULL` ?? any reason ?

Comment: Im not sure, that's clearly wrong.
I need a select statement that only selects the fields that have been populated, but there are so many variations

Comment: Build the query dynamically.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: Here's an example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685881/filter-mysql-query-with-form-options/32686418#32686418. You also should look into updating your driver so you can use parameterized queries which will prevent SQL injections..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define your SQL with only the required criteria

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `hr_employees` WHERE (name_first LIKE '$name_first%')";
```

then add the optional criteria... optionally

```
if ($status) {
    $sql .= " AND (status LIKE '$status%') ";
}

if ($manstaff) {
    $sql .= " AND (manages_staff LIKE '$manstaff%')";
}
$result401=mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error' . mysql_error());
```

Incidentally, please consider updating your code to avoid using the deprecated `mysql` functions, and keep in mind that concatenating variables into your SQL like this makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection.